# Box2d web dynamic shape with image

Tags: javascript, image, box2d

I have problem with box2d web version [This library](http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/)
and I have problem with images. I used before box2dJS but I read that it's older version, so I changed to box2dWeb.
In box2dJS was working `bodyDef.userData = document.getElementById('ball')` where 'ball' was an png image, but in box2dWeb it's not working. I read that documentation to this is from flash, so I asked flash developer how he is doing this, but he also said that it should be bodyDef.userData = imageObject

I really don't know why it doesn't work. Maybe somebody knows how to make dynamic object with connected with image...

Or maybe somebody knows good physics library wrote in js? I need something free

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a link/example of your code, as your friend says I believe you would need to reference a box2d element rather than a dom element